# Why does this puts GC pressure under WPF but not in a console application?

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, garbage-collection

I'm looking to realize a logging window that handles high-throughput under WPF.

There's something that I fundamentally don't understand, why does it put such a high pressure on the GC while the same thing run in a console does not at all.

Code:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1;

public partial class MainWindow
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _builder = new();
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(BackgroundAction);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ForegroundAction);
    }

    private async Task ForegroundAction()
    {
        var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0d / 60.0d);

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);

            await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                string text;

                lock (_syncRoot)
                {
                    text = _builder.ToString();
                }

                TextBox.Text = text;
            });
        }
    }

    private void BackgroundAction()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (_builder.Length > 10000)
                {
                    _builder.Clear();
                }

                _builder.AppendLine(new string(DateTime.Now.ToString("O")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Console:

[image]

```
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{
    private static readonly StringBuilder _builder = new();
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(BackgroundAction);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ForegroundAction);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task ForegroundAction()
    {
        var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0d / 60.0d);

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay);

            string text;

            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                text = _builder.ToString();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }

    private static void BackgroundAction()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (_builder.Length > 10000)
                {
                    _builder.Clear();
                }

                _builder.AppendLine(new string(DateTime.Now.ToString("O")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The hot spot on both versions is `_builder.AppendLine(new string(DateTime.Now.ToString("O")));`.

The dispatcher isn't at fault in WPF, you can even set it to only be called 10 times per second instead of 60 as shown but the code itself will still inflict lots of pressure on the GC.

If this approach is fundamentally wrong, I'm ready to listen to alternatives.

Comment: in WPF version you have lambda in BeginInvoke (`() =>{}`) and extra await

Comment: I've applied your suggestions but that didn't help much unfortunately.

Comment: @aybe You should look at how many TextBlock objects are being created and released. I figure the console just keeps a text buffer and uses something like GDI+ to display the contents but WPF probably has to invalidate its view, do measure override and arrange override a few times each time the text is updated.

Comment: If you run this in a performance profiling tool (such as JetBrains dotTrace) you probably would also find that the WPF version has a bottleneck that corresponds with all the "extra" memory allocations / GC activity. Could be in user code or in system/WPF code, but may point you to the answer.